# Trouble getting Javascript function to work

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, razor, model-view-controller

ORIGINALLY; I had a button trying to call a function but nested inside of a form, the button will trigger submit form event by default:
The advice was to add a 
 to the button tag and I was able to get past my original problem.

My new problem is:

So I have these buttons:
[image: j]

And I want to have these buttons trigger whether or not a date field is hidden or not.

```
    else if (question.Expected_Answer_Type == "Date")
{
    <input type="button" value="Add a Date @ViewBag.QuestionID" onclick="makeDateVisible(#@ViewBag.QuestionID)">

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.QuestionnaireAnswers[i].Answer, Model.Date.ToString("M/d/yyyy"), new { @class = "form-control date hidden", @id = ViewBag.QuestionID }) if (Model.QuestionnaireAnswers == null)

    {
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#@(ViewBag.QuestionID)')
                        .val("@(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString())");
                }

            );
            function makeDateVisible(@ViewBag.QuestionID) {
                alert("Hello");
            } 

        </script>
    }
}
```

I can't seem to get the Alert inside the makeDateVisible to trigger.

inside the browser....
I get the error:
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
and the red line appears at the end of this line:

```
  <input type="button" value="Add a Date @ViewBag.QuestionID" onclick="makeDateVisible(#@ViewBag.QuestionID)">
```

Comment: buttons inside a form I believe innately submit. You could use `event.preventDefault` on each `button` element, or you can simply change the markup and replace the `button` tags with `input` tags with a `type` of `button`

Comment: Add *type=“button”* to the buttons. They do not need to be inputs for this to work. This should prevent the behaviour explained by zfrisch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass #@ViewBag.QuestionID in quotes then it will be treated as string argument

Otherwise, it is treated as variable thus error is generated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a Button tag use an input tag, and add type=“button” to the tag and this should fix your issue. I linked a website for reference.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/button

Comment: I've updated the question... if you are able to let me know what you think is going on here--I'd be glad to mark this as the accepted answer. :)